# How to construct common table with multiple nested queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a number of views that I need to turn into common table because the where condition need to change dynamically. I can only get the common table to work with one sub query. Is it possible to use more then one as in the example below

```
WITH ctTableA AS (Select * FROM tableA WHERE fldAID=A)

WITH ctTableB AS (Select * FROM tableB WHERE fldAID=A)

SELECT * FROM ctTableA
INNER JOIN ctTableB ON ctTableA.fldX=ctTableB.fldX
```

NB:- I know that a simple inner join query of the 2 tables would work for this example but my real query is much more complex.

What I am specifically asking is; Can we have more than 1 with statement within a common table statement

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTEs so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH 
ctTableA AS (Select * FROM tableA WHERE fldAID=A), 
ctTableB AS (Select * FROM tableB WHERE fldAID=A)

SELECT * FROM ctTableA INNER JOIN ctTableB ON ctTableA.fldX=ctTableB.fldX
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, That works at a single level nested query. But what about multilevel nested query eg
`WITH
ctTableA AS (Select * FROM tableA WHERE fldAID=A), ctTableB AS (Select * FROM tableB WHERE fldAID=A),ctQueryA AS (Select * FROM ctTableB Where fldY=Y

SELECT * FROM ctTableA INNER JOIN ctQueryA ON ctTableA.fldX=ctQueryA .fldX`

Comment: Hi Sheils. I have replied to "Can we have more than 1 with statement within a common table statement". I saw that you were declaring multiple WITH's and corrected the code. If that's not what you were after I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sheils That is a different question. Anyway, what prevents you from just trying it out?

Comment: Hi Guys, I have tried is out and it works at single level but I am having trouble at multiple level query. Agree that Sergio has answered the original question. So I will close this one

Comment: Took me a bit putting it together but It worked. Thanks guys